# Desktop graphics performance degradation after reboot (jumpy mousepointer)

Tags: 16.04, unity, intel-graphics, performance

After an unintended  reboot (I pressed the power key on my keyboard accidentally) my machine booted up as usual but soon became unresponsive after login, with the **mouse pointer being very jumpy and window animations and window placement very poor in performance**. The observed behavior is *not permanent* nor does any open GUI application seem to cause this, there are moments when the performance is fast as usual. Performance on a VT is not impacted.

I noticed lots(!) of the following messages in the journal which haven't been there before (I monitor my log files):

```
Jul 22 16:51:38 za25 gnome-session[6431]: libva info: VA-API version 0.40.0
Jul 22 16:51:38 za25 gnome-session[6431]: libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
Jul 22 16:51:38 za25 gnome-session[6431]: libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
Jul 22 16:51:38 za25 gnome-session[6431]: libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_40
Jul 22 16:51:38 za25 gnome-session[6431]: libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
```

I tried different kernels, checked `i965-va-driver` and for recently installed software of the past days. I have no idea what caused this at the moment.

- Desktop environment: Unity
- CPU/board/firmware:

  ```
  $ grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | head -1
  model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  $ dmesg | grep Super
  [    0.000000] DMI: Supermicro Super Server/X11SSZ-QF, BIOS 2.0a 05/03/2017
  ```
- Latest (mainline) kernel:

  ```
  $ uname -a
  Linux za25 4.12.3-041203-generic #201707210343 SMP Fri Jul 21 07:45:26 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- Distribution/release:

  ```
  cat /etc/*release*
  DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
  DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
  DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
  DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
  NAME="Ubuntu"
  VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
  ID=ubuntu
  ID_LIKE=debian
  PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
  VERSION_ID="16.04"
  HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
  SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
  BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
  VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
  UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked top and found [tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) (tracker-examiner) running at high load. I can't recall installing tracker deliberately, I stopped/killed the process which made the log messages about VA-API stop and the GUI become responsive again. Video playback is not affected and as it was before.

It turns out tracker was installed along with gnome-boxes a few days ago and I haven't rebooted since then.

I decide to not open a bug report since I am fine with not using tracker on 16.04 and this hardware at the moment. Upcoming Ubuntu releases may solve the problem in one way or another (ongoing Unity to Gnome transition, better hardware support, …). If it's of any help for investigation, I have (encrypted) drives with terabytes of data that I mount manually (source code/blobs/images/music/videos).

```
Start-Date: 2017-07-09  11:36:27
Commandline: apt install gnome-boxes
Requested-By: livewire (1000)
Install: … gnome-boxes:amd64 (3.18.1-1.1), seabios:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), libaugeas0:amd64 (1.4.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), tracker-extract:amd64 (1.6.2-0ubuntu1.1, automatic) …
```